# javascript Sum two class elements result to class

Tags: javascript

i want to sum two or more elements in javascript how to do can u fix this code better i want only class elements.

```
<div class="txt1">4</div>         
 <div class="txt2">3</div>   
    <script>
        var y = document.getElementsByClassName("txt1").value;
        var z = document.getElementsByClassName("txt2").value;
        var x = +y + +z;
        document.getElementsByClassName("demo")[0].innerHTML = x;
    </script>
 <div class="demo"></div>
```

Comment: Use `id` instead of class, it'll be easier to manipulate the elements using javascript

Comment: i know id is ok but class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is `.getElementsByClassName()` returns `NodeList` so you have to access elements by index as you did for `demo`. Also it is `.innerHTML` and not `.value`.

You could try this:

```js
var get = function(cls) {
  return document.getElementsByClassName(cls)[0];
};

get('demo').innerHTML = +get('txt1').innerHTML + +get('txt2').innerHTML;
```

```html
<div class="txt1">4</div>
<div class="txt2">3</div>
<div class="demo"></div>
```

Note: Move the `script` tag below `demo` div.

```
<div class="demo"></div>
<script>
...
</script>
```

Comment: Great ! @Arvind i use before `script` upper. tks

Answer (score 0):

you can have one class name for all the element whose values you want to add and have different ids for each of them

```
<div class="sum" id="text1">1</div>
<div class="sum" id="text2">2</div>
<div class="sum" id="text3">3</div>

<script>
  var sum_elements = document.getElementsByClassName('sum');
  var sum = 0;
  for (i=0; i<sum_elements.length; i++){
    sum = sum + parseInt(sum_elements[i].innerHTML)
  }
  document.getElementsByClassName("demo")[0].innerHTML = sum;
</script>
```

Comment: i want different class @Manjunath

Comment: `<div class="txt1 sum">1</div>`

Comment: @Henoktwo, if you still want the class names to be different Alex Char's answer works best !

But the use of class names is so that you can group a number of elements. If you want to identify elements uniquely, then you have to use ids.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
 var y = document.getElementsByClassName("txt1")[0].innerHTML;
 var z = document.getElementsByClassName("txt2")[0].innerHTML;
 var x = +y + +z;
 document.getElementsByClassName("demo")[0].innerHTML = x;
```

```html
<div class="txt1">4</div>
<div class="txt2">3</div>
<div class="demo"></div>
```

> Using class for such purpose is not recommended..Use `id` instead

[Plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/VouolRLP0D5EikSXz6Va?p=preview)

Comment: Tks it fine `<script>` must be down